# Property of definite integral $\int_{a+nT}^{b+mT}f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have the property of definite integral that $\int_{a+nT}^{b+nT}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$. But what about this integral $\int_{a+nT}^{b+mT}f(x)dx$, where $T$ is period of $f(x)$.
I proceed like this as $f(x+nT)=f(x) \ \& \ f(x+mT)=f(x)$, so $\int_{a+nT}^{b+mT}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$. For example let $f(x)=sinx$, then $\int_{a+n(2\pi)}^{b+m(2\pi)}sinx \ dx=\int_{a}^{b}sinx \ dx$. But I wonder if we translate the limit by $a+nT$ and $b+nT$ then the length of the interval is the same but in the second case the length of the interval is different because $n\neq m$(maybe).

Pls help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is $(m-n)\int_a^{b+T}f(x)dx$.

Comment: How pls explain!

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{a+kT}^{b+(k+1)T}f(x)dx=\int_a^{b+T}f(y)dy$ by the change of variable $y=x-kT$. Sum this equation w.r.t. $k$ from $k=n$ to $k=m-1$. There are $m-n$ terms and all of them the have the same value $\int_a^{b+T} f(x)dx$.